# Get values of GCCs option params

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, compiler-optimization

With

```
gcc -march=native -Ofast -Q --help=optimize
```

I can get a list of all optimization flags of the GCC and see whether they are activated or not for my option setting (`-march=native -Ofast` is just an example). If I use

```
gcc -march=native -Ofast -Q --help=params
```

I get a list of all possible options parameters with description. However I don't get the values set for those parameters, although the description of the `-Q` options suggests so. My question is: Is it possible to get these parameter values somehow?

Comment: Good question. Judging [from the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options), this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have changed in gcc-5. With gcc-4.9.2, `gcc -march=native -Ofast -Q --help=params` starts with:

```
predictable-branch-outcome  Maximal estimated outcome of branch considered predictable
```

while with gcc-5.1.0, I see:

```
predictable-branch-outcome  default 2 minimum 0 maximum 50
```

The change appears to be from [this commit](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=215704).

Comment: Oh well, then I have to wait for gcc 5 to arrive in my distro. Thanks.